# How to fetch then render react components from database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a collection of react components stored in a database as string. I want to fetch the components from the DB on the client side (browser) and render them.

**Usecase**: Working on a search engine, want to give control to the user on the way results are rendered.

What is the safest way to do this?

---

Comment: What do you mean you have components stored in a database? Besides the fact that you probably shouldn't be doing that (unless you have a super unique use case), in what format are they stored?

Comment: Could you describe what purpose you want to achieve?

Comment: Updated the question to describe the usecase.

Comment: @Harsh you didn't say how they were stored. And based on your use case, that shouldn't require you to store the actual components themselves. Plus this question is just too broad. Needs more info and should be focused around a single, specific problem

Answer (score 1):

you can use "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" property like below:

```
var databaseTags = "<p>ok</P>";

...
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: databaseTags }}></div>
...
```

Answer (score -2):

This method bind to DOM directly

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<p>Jhon &middot; Smith</p>'}}></div>
```

Comment: This was already suggested by @kingofday and is dangerous, do you have a safer suggestion?